# Прокомментируйте что происходит в js коде

Tags: javascript

```js
    var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('#messages-container .remove-button');

    for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
      var button = buttons[i];

      button.onclick = function() {
        var el = this.parentNode;
        el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
      };
    }
```

```css
body {
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 470px;
}

h3 {
  margin: 0;
  padding-bottom: .3em;
  font-size: 1.1em;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 .5em;
}

.pane {
  background: #edf5e1;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px;
  border-top: solid 2px #c4df9b;
  position: relative;
}

.remove-button {
  font-size: 110%;
  color: darkred;
  right: 10px;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
  <div id="messages-container">
    <div class="pane">
      <h3>Лошадь</h3>
      <p>Домашняя лошадь — животное семейства непарнокопытных, одомашненный и единственный сохранившийся подвид дикой лошади, вымершей в дикой природе, за исключением небольшой популяции лошади Пржевальского.</p>
      <button class="remove-button">[x]</button>
    </div>
    <div class="pane">
      <h3>Осёл</h3>
      <p>Домашний осёл или ишак — одомашненный подвид дикого осла, сыгравший важную историческую роль в развитии хозяйства и культуры человека. Все одомашненные ослы относятся к африканским ослам.</p>
      <button class="remove-button">[x]</button>
    </div>
    <div class="pane">
      <h3>Корова, а также пара слов о диком быке, о волах и о тёлках. </h3>
      <p>Коро́ва — самка домашнего быка, одомашненного подвида дикого быка, парнокопытного жвачного животного семейства полорогих. Самцы вида называются быками, молодняк — телятами, кастрированные самцы — волами. Молодых (до первой стельности) самок называют
        тёлками.
      </p>
      <button class="remove-button">[x]</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

непонятно что происходит когда кликаем на button

Comment: Очевидно удаляется родительский элемент. Какая строчка непонятна?

Comment: @Alexey Ten       var el = this.parentNode; el.parentNode.removeChild(el);

Comment: И что тут непонятного? Взяли родителя. Родителю родителя (дедушке) сказали удалить ребёнка который родитель.

Comment: @Grundy  я знаю значение remove; непонятно el = this.parentNode;  el.parentNode

Comment: @xes [parentNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode)

Comment: @Grundy там по-английски :(((

Comment: @xes, просто выбери русский язык.

Comment: @Grundy компьютерный перевод карявый

Comment: @xes, кто говорит про компьютерный? Там люди переводят. Внизу страницы есть выбор языка

Comment: @Grundy  а ВЫ откуда знаете ?

Comment: @Grundy parentNode это родительский узел this.parentNode это ссылка на родительский узел;  el.parentNode ссылка на родительский узел родительского узла это будет div class="pane" правильно ?

Comment: в зависимости от разметки

Comment: @xes, я тоже участвовал в переводе

Comment: @Grundy спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При клике на `button` вызывается функция `button.onclick` => получается родительский элемент кнопки (зеленый прямоугольник с текстом и кнопкой) => через родительский элемент зеленого прямоугольника(это контейнер) удаляется выбранный зеленый прямоугольник (через `removeChild` - удалить дочерний элемент)

Comment: непонятно el = this.parentNode; el.parentNode